# rhino doesn't show up in eclipse Luna launch config

Tags: eclipse, rhino

I checked under about/plugins and the rhino javascript is there but rhino isn't an option under   Eclipse Luna launch debug. Remote javascript is a launch option however. Windows 8 64 bit. thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I had to copy org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.debug.rhino.ui_1.0..jar from the plugins directory of kepler into luna.